# Is it possible to use turbolinks without using require_tree?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'd like to use turbolinks in my application, but I'm hesitant to use 'require_tree' in application.js, the reason being that I have specific code that's supposed to be loaded ONLY in particular controllers.

If I leave require_tree out of application.js, none of the coffescripts are loaded at all, which automatically makes them useless.

I'm having a hard time understanding how turbolinks works, so forgive me if this is a really silly question.

Thanks.

EDIT: Example:

I have 3 controllers, Users, Products and Sales. Each controller has their own .js.coffee file with code that pertains only to their controller.

users.js.coffee:

```
$ ->
  $('#d_table').dataTable
    sPaginationType: "bootstrap"
  $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

products.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('#r_chart').highcharts
    chart:
      type: 'spline'
```

sales.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $("#r_chart").highcharts
    chart:
      type: "column"
```

If I enable require_tree and turbolinks in application.js, an exception is raised cause I'm binding two events to #r_chart (as expected), but they sorta "work", albeit with lots of errors (that's a total different situation for another day).

If I disable require_tree but leave turbolinks enabled, none of the js.coffee files are load, so no events are fired from jQuery.

If I disable require_tree and turbolinks, the application works as expected. The js.coffee files are loaded individually per controller, and all the events fire when called.

--

What I'm trying to do is to have the third scenario, where turbolinks is enabled, but the js.coffee files are individually loaded per controller (instead of being loaded altogether with require_tree).

Comment: Yes. If you are having problem with specific code, share that code and we can help with it.

Comment: The code isn't complicated, but it's very specific to certain controllers/methods, so when I have an event bound via jquery to an element, they raise exceptions when loaded with require_tree, as they're only found in those particular controllers. I'll try to provide a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

> **I'm having a hard time understanding how turbolinks works**

[Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) is a Javascript library which is designed to make your application more efficient:

> Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster.
>   Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS
>   between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and
>   replaces only the body and the title in the head. Think CGI vs
>   persistent process.

It works by reloading the `<body>` tag of your webpage, leaving the `<head>` tag intact - limiting the amount of data to be requested & rendered each time.

The problem with Turbolinks is your javascript often loses its ability to "bind" with elements in the `DOM` - meaning you've got to use some of the [`Turbolinks` event hooks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) or [`Javascript` delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) to make your JS work correctly:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var your_function = function() {
  // ... your functionality
}

$(document).on("page:load ready", your_function);
```

--

**Controller-Centric Assets**

If you want to load controller-centric assets, it won't be an issue with Turbolinks or `require_tree` - it will be an issue with how you're loading the files you need.

I would recommend using the [`controller_name` helper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/controller_name/class) in your layout like this:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag  "application", controller_name, media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

This will allow you to load up only the controller-specific assets in your layout, treating each one exclusive to the `require_tree` directive.

[`require_tree`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) is just part of the sprockets system to include other files into your main `application.___` asset file. If you don't want to include other controller-specific files in the `application` file, just load them individually & use the [`config.assets.precompile`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) option to manage them:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += ["your.css", "controller.css", "files.css"]
```

---

**Fix**

Perhaps the problem you have is to do with the binding of your elements?

You're using an anonymous function to initiate the binding on `DOM` load - perhaps you'd be better using the [Turbolinks events](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events) to sort it out:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var loading = function() {
   //highcharts stuff here
}

$(document).on("page:load ready", loading);
```

Comment: I think I'm getting close with your suggestion. I'm not having issues with binding them on the DOM (I'm using a gem that replaces my code to use the proper page:load instruction)., so that part is fine. I tried to use the controller_name helper as you suggested, but I'm getting an error, which I assume it's cause of the absence of config.assets.precompile which I haven't added yet. The problem is that this problem only exists in development, if I publish it to production it works fine without any modification, but I cannot work with it at all in development.

Comment: So, my question is, would this have to be precompiled? Even if it's just in the development environment? The error is this btw: "*Asset filtered out and will not be served: add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( welcome.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server*"

Comment: I noticed something, instead of `stylesheet_link_tag`, I think you actually meant `javascript_include_tag`, right? Anyway, I tried it that way, and added `config.assets.precompile` to my assets.rb, and now the application behaves like turbolinks isn't enabled at all.

Comment: I've managed to make it load the coffescripts individually by adding the following line to my application.html.haml after %body `= javascript_include_tag controller_name, 'data-turbolinks-track' => true`. It almost works, the only problem at this point is that the script is loaded multiple times whenever I visit the page again (which is expected). Is there a way to prevent that? I realize that the reason for this is cause I'm loading it on <body> instead of <head>, but this is the closest I've got to resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `require_tree`. You can require each javascript individually with:

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require some_other_file
```

More [here in the section 2.2.1 Search Paths](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets#search-paths).

Comment: That's not really the issue, though. I'm talking about the controller-specific coffeescripts. These .js.coffee files are the ones that aren't loaded when turbolinks is enabled without require_tree.

Comment: I see, then the solution isn't the `application.js` manifest since its purpose is to provide Sprockets with a list of files to concatenate into a single file in production. You'll need to manually `javascript_include_tag 'specific_file'` where you want it. If you're placing your scripts in the head you can use the `yield :some_content` and `content_for :some_content` technique to place your scripts in the head from the specific controller action you want it in.

Comment: I'm confused. These files are the standard .js.coffee files that come with each controller, there're no additional files created. When turbolinks is disabled (along with require_tree) the application works as expected, but as soon as turbolinks is enabled, none of them are loaded. I edited my question to reflect what I'm talking about.